# UTF-8 Encoding in java, retrieving data from website

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding

I'm trying to get data from website which is encoded in UTF-8 and insert them into the database (MYSQL). Database is also encoded in UTF-8.

This is the method I use to download data from specific site.

```
public String download(String url) throws java.io.IOException {
        java.io.InputStream s = null;
        java.io.InputStreamReader r = null;
        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            s = (java.io.InputStream)new URL(url).getContent();

            r = new java.io.InputStreamReader(s, "UTF-8");

            char[] buffer = new char[4*1024];
            int n = 0;
            while (n >= 0) {
                n = r.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                if (n > 0) {
                    content.append(buffer, 0, n);
                }
            }
        }
        finally {
            if (r != null) r.close();
            if (s != null) s.close(); 
        }
        return content.toString();
    }
```

If encoding is set to 'UTF-8' (r = new java.io.InputStreamReader(s, "UTF-8"); ) data inserted into database seems to look OK, but when I try to display it, I am getting something like this: C�te d'Ivoire, instead of Côte d'Ivoire.

All my websites are encoded in UTF-8.

Please help.

If encoding is set to 'windows-1252' (r = new java.io.InputStreamReader(s, "windows-1252"); ) everything works fine and I am getting Côte d'Ivoire on my website (), but in java this title looks like 'C?´te d'Ivoire' what breaks other things, such as for example links. What does it mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your database encoding set to UTF-8 for both server, client, connection and have the tables been created with that encoding? Check 'show variables' and 'show create table `<one-of-the-tables>`'

Comment: character set client: utf8; character set connection: utf8; character set database: latin1; character set filesystem: binary; character set results: utf8; character set server: latin1; character set system: utf8;

Comment: Well, there you have it. Your server stores the data as 'latin1' (unless you specifically set 'utf8' when creating the tables. You need to set that server 'character set' (it's actually a character encoding, but let's not go into that now) to utf8 as well.

Answer (score 7):

I would consider using commons-io, they have a function doing what you want to do:[link](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString(java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String))

That is replace your code with this:

```
public String download(String url) throws java.io.IOException {
    java.io.InputStream s = null;
    String content = null;
    try {
        s = (java.io.InputStream)new URL(url).getContent();
        content = IOUtils.toString(s, "UTF-8")

    }
    finally {
        if (s != null) s.close(); 
    }
    return content.toString();
}
```

if that nots doing start looking into if you can store it to file correctly to eliminate the possibility that your db isn't set up correctly.

Comment: Database encoding: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8) , all tables are in UTF-8 (ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;)

Comment: Try using commonsIO http://commons.apache.org/io/
Thats instead of the conversion your doing in the first post. You get a one liner for doing that.

Answer (score 2):

**Java**

The problem seems to lie in the `HttpServletResponse` , if you have a servlet or jsp page. Make sure to set your `HttpServletResponse` encoding to UTF-8.

In a jsp page or in the `doGet` or `doPost` of a servlet, before any content is sent to the response, just do :

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

**PHP**

In PHP, try to use the [utf8-encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) function after retrieving from the database.

Comment: I am using php/apache, and YES, I set encoding to UTF-8:
header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8');

Comment: Be careful that setting the header does not mean setting the encoding. You should specify in your question that you are using PHP/apache, because your java code makes this ambiguous.

Comment: you need to define the encoding when you write it as well, don't know how this works in PHP, but what you're setting in the comment is just a instruction on how the client should interpret the content stream.

Answer (score 1):

> *If encoding is set to 'UTF-8' (r = new java.io.InputStreamReader(s, "UTF-8"); ) data inserted into database seems to look OK, but when I try to display it, I am getting something like this: C�te d'Ivoire, instead of Côte d'Ivoire.*

Thus, the encoding **during** the display is wrong. How are you displaying it? As per the comments, it's a PHP page? If so, then you need to take two things into account:

1. Write them to HTTP response output using the same encoding, thus `UTF-8`.
2. Set content type to `UTF-8` so that the webbrowser knows which encoding to use to display text.

As per the comments, you have apparently already done 2. Left behind 1, in PHP you need to install `mb_string` and set `mbstring.http_output` to `UTF-8` as well. I have found [this cheatsheet](http://developer.loftdigital.com/blog/php-utf-8-cheatsheet) very useful.